# Calling ChaiScript function defined in another script file

Tags: function, scripting, call, chaiscript

How to call a ChaiScript function defined in a script file (e.g. "functions.chai")?

I have appended `use("functions.chai")` in the header of my calling script file but it did not work.

I would appreciate your help as I'm starting to have many functions within the same script which is not very convenient.

Answer (score 0):

The relative path to the included file was not correct. Hence, one should write something like use("C:\path\to\included\file.chai").